# Entity Framework Code First and Connection Strings

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have a small MVC 3 app using Entity Framework Code First and use this connection string for the model:

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Journal.mdf;User Instance=true;Database=MyJournal
```

When I make a change to the model (e.g. add a property), I get as expected

> The model backing the 'JournalContext' context has changed since the database was created.

So, being in development mode, I go ahead and delete Journal.mdf and Journal.ldf.

Now when I run the application again, I get

> Cannot open database "MyJournal" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.

If I change my connection string to

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Journal.mdf;User Instance=true;Database=MyJournal2
```

(changed the `Database=` parameter by appending '2')

Journal.mdf is created and the app works again.  If I make a number of changes and attempt to "recycle" any Database name again, I get the "Cannot open" error.

Why do I need to provide a unique Database name each time I change the model, and how can I "clean out" previous names?

Comment: Are you restarting the application after deleting the database?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Yes, I am.  I get the error upon starting the app again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a unique database name each time.  When a model is first created, it runs a DatabaseInitializer to do things like create the database if it's not there or add seed data. The default DatabaseInitializer tries to compare the database schema needed to use the model with a hash of the schema stored in an EdmMetadata table that is created with a database (when Code First is the one creating the database).  If the hash comparison is different then it throws that error.

Obviously if you change the connection string then its going to create an entirely new database called 'MyJournal2'.

Ways to get around this are to delete the EdmMetadata table and run the initializer again.  You can do this by going into the Database Explorer window in Visual Studio and connecting to your database, then going to Tables where you should find the EdmMetadata table, right-clicking on it and selecting Delete.

Alternatively put

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<dbType>());
```

in your `Application_Start` method in Global.asax.cs.  This will delete the database and recreate it whenever the schema changes.

See [this video on pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer?author=scott-allen&name=mvc3-building-data-i&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro) for more details, especially the section '**When classes change**'.

Also check this link for [DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604%28v=VS.103%29.aspx).  It tells you about what actually happens and how to seed the database if you need to by creating a derived class.

Comment: Why am I getting the "permission denied" error when I delete the .mdf file?  Where is the EdmMetadata table if not in the deleted .mdf file?

Comment: I have updated my answer on how to delete the EdmMetadata table.  I highly recommend you watch the video I linked to, it tells you everything you need to know.  You could be getting a "permission denied" error for quite a few reasons, one being that the webserver is still running and accessing that database.

Comment: And yes, I would have assumed that if you deleted the .mdf file then the database itself should have been removed, including the EdmMetadata table.  How are you deleting the database? Through an SQL Express manager?

Comment: On further inspection I see you are just deleting the files and not the database itself. By deleting the .mdf and .ldf files, you are only removing the data and logs files.  Information regarding the database and its file locations are stored in the sql server master database so you need to remove it from there as well through either the database explorer or sql server/express management studio.

Comment: I don't see any mention of the "Journal" database in SQL Server Management Studio.  I looked under the Databases node of Object Explorer and in sys.Databases.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure then.  Did you say you were getting a permission denied error when deleting the .mdf file? Have you tried putting in the SetInitializer call?

Comment: No, getting the error when running the app.  Adding the call to SetInitializer does correctly initialize the DB even after changes, so the problem is basically solved, but it seems there must be dead references to the couple names I used when trying to figure this out.  Kind of irritating not knowing how to clean it up, but the basic issue is solved.

Comment: You are definitely connecting to the correct sql express instance?  The only adviceI can think of would be to reinitialize the database under all the names you have used and manually delete them from SQL Server Management Studio rather than deleting the files themselves.