# How get EF to create db in my App_Data folder MVC

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

When I make a MVC 4 application and use 'Code First' with Entity Framework, it 'magically' creates the database based on my model. However I'd like this database to be put into the project App_Data folder and not some random place on my computer.

How can I do this? I'm guessing I need to add something to the Web.config but that's about all I can guess.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the AttachDbFilename and |DataDirectory| within you're connection string like so:

data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|dbName.mdf;User Instance=true;Database=dbName

See full example here

[Entity Framework Code First and Connection Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249929/entity-framework-code-first-and-connection-strings)